# Java Generating Strings Recursively - All 1s then 1 and 0

Tags: java, string, recursion, arraylist

Hey guys I'm trying to get the concept of recursion down by making a program that generates `String` of an `ArrayList` recursively.  My basic algorithm is:

```
public static ArrayList<String> generateListOfAll1sStrings(int maxBits)
```

**terminal condition:** if maxBits is 1, return the simplest case: a list containing just "1"

**otherwise:**
recursively call `generateListOfAll1sStrings()` for the next-smallest bit-length, saving the list that is returned
find the longest string in that list and create a new string with "1" appended to it (making the next-longest string)
return a new list that contains all the elements of the shorter list along with the new string just added.

The code I have so far is:

```
    package bincomb.model;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class BinaryCombinationGenerator {

public static ArrayList<String> generateListOfAll1sStrings(int maxBits) {
    String string = null;
    ArrayList<String> listofJust1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> otherArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 1;


    if (maxBits == 1) {
        listofJust1.add("1");
        return listofJust1;
    }

    if (maxBits > 1) {
        for (String string2 : listofJust1) {
            String comp = "";
            if (!(comp.equals(string2))) {
                comp = string2;
            }
            string = comp;
        }
        listofJust1.add(i, (string + "1"));
        i++;
        listofJust1 = BinaryCombinationGenerator.generateListOfAll1sStrings((maxBits-1));

        System.out.println(listofJust1);
        return listofJust1;
    }

    return listofJust1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateListOfAll1sStrings(10);
}

}
```

However, currently, I'm returning an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  I think my for loop is causing the problem, but I'm not certain how to go about fixing it.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception

Comment: listofJust1.add(i,(string+"1")) and of course my main method line generateListOfAll1sString(10);

Comment: string = comp, what is this string variable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` at this line `listofJust1.add(i, (string + "1"));`.

This is because the method list.add(index, objects) tries to add the object at index "1" but your array has 0 elements.

Either change it to `listofJust1.add(i-1, (string + "1"));` or simply `listofJust1.add((string + "1"));`

@Edit: here:

```
listofJust1.add(i, (string + "1"));
```

You want to add the string for the current (N) level of recursion but below you substitute this array with:

```
listofJust1 = BinaryCombinationGenerator.generateListOfAll1sStrings((maxBits-1));
```

Which basically says "get the result for (maxBits-1) and replace with it listofJust1" therefore you are losing what you added before.

Instead you should first get the list for level N-1 and then add the string for the current level:

```
listofJust1 = BinaryCombinationGenerator.generateListOfAll1sStrings((maxBits-1));
listofJust1.add(stringForThisLevel);
```

Also you need to rething how you are computing "string" at level N, doesn't seem right.

Comment: I took your advice and changed it to listofJust1.add((string+"1")), and I got an output an ArrayList of 9 elements of an arrayList with only [1] in them.  The program is supposed to add a 1 each time concluding with the final time, in this case, should be 10 so: [1][11][111][1111][11111][111111][1111111][11111111][111111111][1111111111]  I tried doing this adding by having the + "1".  How can that be done differently?

Comment: @Dan no it "printed" 9x[1]. The resulting list has only 1 element [1] because at each level of recursion you are creating a new list with 1 element and return it up the recursion tree.

Comment: @Dan no problem! recursion is quite difficult but don't falter, it's amazing when you get good at it :-)